# Is it possible to verify the hostname in a reliable way?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloudfunction that I want to be called only when the requests originates from my domain.

```
export const createMatch = functionUS.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth === null || context.auth?.uid == null || data?.userId !== context.auth?.uid)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "not authenticated");

  try {
    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid);
    if (!user.displayName) throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "username is missing");
    data.username = user.displayName;

    const matchRepo = new MatchRepository(new FirestoreMatchProvider("matches"));
    const match = Match.fromMap(new Map<string, any>(Object.entries(data)));
    if (!match.isValid()) throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "match data is not valid");
    await matchRepo.createMatch(match, context.auth.uid);
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(`handleMatchCreate: ${error}`);
  }
});
```

I noticed that the express has the hostname option which I can take from the context, but this is just a header for the hostname. And from what I read this could be faked. Is there any way for me to know if the requests originated from my domain?

Because someone could look into the code and get my firebase config and make an application for himself which just sends requests whenever he wants. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of HTTP Protocol, you can't change it. Simply don't rely on the network layer (DNS and IP). You can't do more